# How to use many git repositories in a project

Tags: git, gitlab

I clone a project on github and add some small features. I have changed code in **many functions of some files**. I want to organize my project as below:

- Branch master: to update the new code from **original repository**
- Branch dev: contains my modified code, and need to update to **my git repository**
- A fast method to merge the new code from the original repository into my dev branch. Now, when I merge branch master into dev, it overwrite all modified files.

Could you give me a sample ? Thank you !

Comment: Title does not really match the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you did something along these lines:

```
git clone <path>
git checkout dev
# make changes
git add .
git commit
```

Now you should do:

```
git checkout dev
git fetch <remote>
git merge <remote>/master
```

It's possible you will run into conflicts that you must resolve during the merge.

Comment: Thank for your reply. My project has many unknown conflicts, probably I will create my project again.